# share image intent image is an actually url of image not an application resource

Tags: android, share

Actually I am getting all rss feed from [here](http://9gagrss.com/feed/)
Now I all complete with my code But I want to add one functionality of share image.

Now I have image linke for ex.

`http://miscmedia-9gag-lol.9cache.com/images/long-post-cover/12796580_1414746906.7976_Ejy2yj_460c.jpg`  [link](http://miscmedia-9gag-lol.9cache.com/images/long-post-cover/12796580_1414746906.7976_Ejy2yj_460c.jpg)

How can I share this image like sharing an regular image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved such issue by downloading image before sharing. (If you display images in your app using library like universal image loader or implemented such functionality on your own the only thing you need to do is to find predownloaded image on file system) If image is not large it will not take much time to download. Then you can delete image file after sharing.

Comment: I have result image in bitmap but how to store bitmap to such location and then share

Answer (score -1):

try this,

```
Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, imageurl);
shareIntent.setType("image/*");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share images to..");
```

Comment: While this may be the answer to the question, a few words of explanation would be even more helpful to future readers.